logstash parsing error "but found a concrete value"
I have errors in from logstash, regarding this part of a logline
"status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [message] tried to parse field [message] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}

when logstash is trying to parse this part of a logline
"message":"readOrdersByContractNumber(1687687485, NONE)"

I want to understand the problem
